# vb.net datatype in manually added column

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim pctofpax As New DataColumn
        pctofpax = New DataColumn("PCTPAX1", GetType(Decimal))
        pctofpax.Expression = "[ASOFPAX] / [YEPAX]"
        ds.Tables("workplease").Columns.Add(pctofpax)

        Dim avgppax As New DataColumn
        avgppax = New DataColumn("AVG PAX", GetType(Double))
        avgppax.Expression = "[Current Sales] / [Current PAX]"
        ds.Tables("workplease").Columns.Add(avgppax)
```

These are two columns that i added into my asp.net/vb.net datagrid. the problem is i keep trying to change the datatypes so they show up as numbers with only two decimals but it is not working

```
            <span lang="en-us">Sales As Of Analysis</span><br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
            GridLines="Vertical">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PCTPAX1" 
                 HeaderText="PCTPAX1" 
                 DataFormatString="{0:c}">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and nothing happend to my data

Comment: Define "not working."  How is it failing?  Is it simply a matter of formatting the values in the display to show only two decimals?  Or is there some other issue?

Comment: well i tried doing a decimal(10,2) and that isn't working maybe i am just doing it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a matter of displaying only two decimals, this can be accomplished in the display code for the `DataGrid`:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PCTPAX1" 
                 HeaderText="PCTPAX1" 
                 DataFormatString="{0:c}">
```

Note the `DataFormatString` value of `{0:c}` which specifies that the formatting of the value in that field should be "currency."  (You can also try with a capital `C`, I don't have a test handy for it right now.)  There's a lot more you can do with format strings, more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Or do you want the actual values to be rounded to currency values?  You'll likely use `Math.Round` for that, though I don't have an example handy.  There's information about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx).

**Edit:** Based on your comment(s), it sounds like you were attempting to change data types at the database level.  This won't really impact the code.  The value coming back from the database in the form of a double or decimal or some other numeric likely won't carry that precision back to the code.  As far as the `DataGrid` is concerned, it's calling `.ToString()` on a `double` and showing the result.  No database data type is involved.  Using the `DataFormatString` property to pass a format string to the `.ToString()` method is how to change the display.

**Edit again based on your question edit:** Your HTML is broken.  You have the BoundColumn outside of the grid, and the column tag itself isn't closed.  Columns go inside the grid.  See the grid layout [here](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=18).  Basically, you'd want something more like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
              BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
              GridLines="Vertical">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PCTPAX1" 
                         HeaderText="PCTPAX1" 
                         DataFormatString="{0:c}">
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: is there a way i can do it for the entire table i never want to see more then 2 decimals

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: Not that I know of.  Each column is its own data type and its own data.  How many columns are we talking about?  Adding `DataFormatString` to each one shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: yeah i dont care how the values are written in the database, because i don't plan on allowing an update from my program to the database, the main concern is viewing purposes. However, it looks really messy with 0000 everywhere

Comment: Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'asp:BoundColumn' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundColumn'.

Comment: Ah, you're using a `GridView` and it looks like the `BoundColumn` control doesn't work with that.  Try `BoundField` instead.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Second time you saved my life today.

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: Glad I could help.  Though you're pushing me further and further away from an Unsung Hero badge on this site.  Not that I mind the upvotes or anything :)

Comment: for me as long as i am learning, the badges and points don't mean much. the knowledge is enough, and when it comes to asp.net and sql i lack a lot of it.

Comment: but your going to kill me haha the columns are showing up twice now

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: Did you remove the duplicated one(s) from the SQL query?

Comment: yeah i tryed it and i got 
A field or property with the name 'DYYYY' was not found on the selected data source.

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: Where is that field created?  In the SQL query or in the code?  Where is it referenced?  It sound like you either removed or renamed a bound field that code is using.

Comment: its created from the query, whenever i add a column or formatstring in my asp side. it makes a column and my vb.net side is making a column too

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: It's likely that there's just something small that's been overlooked.  However, the code involved isn't available.  You could either update your question or ask a new one and include more code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of a column which is already in your datatable doesn't work. or at least not that i know. if you just want to get a different formatting, look at the answers above.